# CNN program has been computing for too long and not giving any output

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I've implemented the following code in Jupyter notebook, and it has been over 90 mins, the programme is still running, and I've not gotten any output.

I'm working with mid-2012 MacBook Pro.
4 GB ram.
I've checked the activity monitor, memory pressure is in the yellow zone, so that means, the means, the mac is not running out of memory, and I don't know what to do now.

The program implements CNN model over CIFAR-10 dataset.

````
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

# load train and test dataset
def load_dataset():
    # load dataset
    (trainX, trainY), (testX, testY) = cifar10.load_data()
    # one hot encode target values
    trainY = to_categorical(trainY)
    testY = to_categorical(testY)
    return trainX, trainY, testX, testY

# scale pixels
def prep_pixels(train, test):
    # convert from integers to floats
    train_norm = train.astype('float32')
    test_norm = test.astype('float32')
    # normalize to range 0-1
    train_norm = train_norm / 255.0
    test_norm = test_norm / 255.0
    # return normalized images
    return train_norm, test_norm

# define cnn model
def define_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    # compile model
    opt = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# plot diagnostic learning curves
def summarize_diagnostics(history):
    # plot loss
    pyplot.subplot(211)
    pyplot.title('Cross Entropy Loss')
    pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], color='blue', label='train')
    pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], color='orange', label='test')
    # plot accuracy
    pyplot.subplot(212)
    pyplot.title('Classification Accuracy')
    pyplot.plot(history.history['accuracy'], color='blue', label='train')
    pyplot.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], color='orange', label='test')
    # save plot to file
    filename = sys.argv[0].split('/')[-1]
    pyplot.savefig(filename + '_plot.png')
    pyplot.close()

# run the test harness for evaluating a model
def run_test_harness():
    # load dataset
    trainX, trainY, testX, testY = load_dataset()
    # prepare pixel data
    trainX, testX = prep_pixels(trainX, testX)
    # define model
    model = define_model()
    # create data generator
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1, horizontal_flip=True)
    # prepare iterator
    it_train = datagen.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=64)
    # fit model
    steps = int(trainX.shape[0] / 64)
    history = model.fit_generator(it_train, steps_per_epoch=steps, epochs=100, validation_data=(testX, testY), verbose=0)
    # evaluate model
    _, acc = model.evaluate(testX, testY, verbose=0)
    print('> %.3f' % (acc * 100.0))
    # learning curves
    summarize_diagnostics(history)

# entry point, run the test harness
run_test_harness()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your model is taking so long to train is because:

1. You are training a large model with many layers for 100 epochs
2. You are using a relatively low performance computer (from what I found googling it only has a 2.5 GHZ processor.)

You can make it train faster by using an a free cloud environment that has GPUs and TPUs like Google Colab (https://colab.research.google.com/), or even better a Kaggle notebook which allows you to train for longer periods of time. If you want to run it on your mac you could try making the model smaller or decreasing the number of epochs you are training for.

It should be easy to port your notebook to a Google Colab or Kaggle notebook. You will need to create a google account for Google Colab or a seperate account for Kaggle.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

You need High GPU Operating system to run this on Jypyter Notebook. otherwise use **Google Colab** (https://colab.research.google.com/), Due to high value of epoch it will take a large amount of time in jupyter notebook